# Computing the complex eigenvectors of a sparse matrix in Java

Tags: eigenvalue, eigenvector, apache-commons-math, jama, mtj

I am trying to compute the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a potentially large and sparse non-symmetrical `NxN` matrix (`N` > 10^6). I would not need all of them, but maybe the  first of them. Ideally, I'd like to do so from Java but could move to C, C++ or Python if required.

My matrix can potentially have both complex eigenvalues and eigenvectors. For example, see the results for [this Wolfram Alpha sample](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvectors+%7B%7B0,+1%2F3,+2%2F3,+0,0,0%7D,+%7B1%2F2,+0,+1%2F3,+0,0,0%7D,+%7B1%2F2,+2%2F3,+0,+0,0,0%7D,+%7B0,0,0,0,+4%2F5,+0%7D,+%7B0,0,0,1%2F4,+0,+1%2F3%7D,+%7B0,0,0,3%2F4,+1%2F5,+0%7D%7D).

I found several ways to do this using a number of Java libraries and wrote some evaluation code for them:

- [Commons-Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/linear.html): [`EigenDecomposition`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/EigenDecomposition.html)
- [JAMA](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/): [`EigenvalueDecomposition`](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/doc/Jama/EigenvalueDecomposition.html)
- [MTJ](https://github.com/fommil/matrix-toolkits-java): [`EVD`](http://static.javadoc.io/com.googlecode.matrix-toolkits-java/mtj/1.0.4/no/uib/cipr/matrix/EVD.html)
- [COLT](http://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/): [`EigenvalueDecomposition`](http://dst.lbl.gov/ACSSoftware/colt/api/cern/colt/matrix/linalg/EigenvalueDecomposition.html)

But the problem I am facing is that these libraries do not return (or at least I found no way to get) the **complex valued eigenvectors**. Most of them do return the complex valued eigen*values*, but not complex eigen*vectors*. They typically provide the latter in the form of a "vector of reals" or "real matrix" having columns as each eigenvector.

I do as a matter of fact need the eigenvalues in complex form, if any.

Now, I recently started looking into [Spectra](http://spectralib.org/) (C++) which [seems to support my use case](http://spectralib.org/doc/classspectra_1_1geneigssolver). But would like to first ask and maybe discard a misunderstanding on my side or something I may have skipped from Java land because I'd like to keep using a single platform/language as far as it's possible.

Is there anything I should be looking into? Also, If I end up moving away from Java for this task, any other alternatives to Spectra I could be looking into? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this, I finally went the C++ way because none of the Java libraries provided the complex eigenvectors as I needed.

I have ended up implementing most of the stuff I need with C++ using Spectra and Eigen. Then I have built a series of native wrapper classes using SWIG.

Answer (score 0):

For everyone in the future with the same question: there is a library for Java called Jeigen that can do this. It is actually a Java wrapper for the Eigen C++ library that the original poster already mentioned in his own answer.

You can find Jeigen [here](https://github.com/hughperkins/jeigen).